# How do I get the field label from a node object?

Tags: 8

I've tried guessing

```
$node->field_name->fieldDefinition->label
$node->field_name->fieldDefinition->label()
```

and

```
$node->field_name->label
$node->field_name->label()
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your first guess was very close, but both are protected properties, so are accessed by getters - functions with the prefix `get`:

```
$field_label = $node->field_name->getFieldDefinition()->getLabel();
```

For reference:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemInterface.php/interface/FieldItemInterface/8.2.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldDefinitionInterface.php/interface/FieldDefinitionInterface/8.2.x

**Edit:**

Btw, in twig you don't need the prefix `get`, because if you tell twig to get something with the name `label`, it  tests all possibilities on the object, first it tries to access the property `label`, then the method `label()` and finally the getter `getLabel()`.

```
{{ node.field_name.fielddefinition.label }}
```

Comment: `$node->field_name->getfieldDefinition()->label();` also works without the `get` for the label only.

Comment: That only works because for configurable fields, the field definition is a config entity and has the label() method. FieldDefinitionInterface defines getLabel(), label() would not work on $node->title->getFieldDefinition(). if you use $node->get('field_name'), then you should also get autocomplete of method names if you use an IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To extend this.. does anyone have any idea of how to set the label in the node? Is there such a thing along the lines of setFieldDefinition?

Comment: @cwiggo, that's no problem, you can set the label in the config of the field. You find it in an exported config in `field.field.node.content_type.field_name.yml`

Comment: @4k4 but i'm trying to change it depending on a taxonomy term id.. any ideas?

Comment: @cwiggo, hard to tell what is the best place to change it with that little information. If you get the term from node content probably no point in getting back to config. Perhaps this is a simple solution in theming what you output instead of the configured label.

Comment: @4k4 the term is applied at the node level yes. So i'm thinking of another solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To get the field label in Twig (in this case in a node-NODETYPE.html.twig):

```
{{ content.field_FIELDNAME['#title'] }}
```