# How to access a selected label instead of value

Tags: 8

I have a select list of states:

```
AL|Alabama
AK|Alaska
AZ|Arizona
AR|Arkansas
```

In code to access the selected state value I can run code like this:

```
...
$entity->get('field_state')->value;
...
```

I get the values like AL or AK.  How can I get the labels like Alabama or Alaska?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201064/how-do-i-get-the-field-label-from-a-node-object

Comment: That only pertains to getting the field's label. I am looking for a selected value from a select list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way but I got the value by getting the allowed values first.

```
$allowed_values = $state->getFieldDefinition('field_state')->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getSetting('allowed_values');
$state_value = $state->get('field_state')->value;
$info['state_name'] = $allowed_values[$state_value];
```

Comment: Geting the allowed values is basically the right way, but getting that can be easier: $state->getFieldDefinition('field_state')->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getSetting('allowed_values').

Answer (score 5):

The proper way is to use **options_allowed_values()** function. Because the field might not have "allowed_values" setting and options can be provided through the "allowed_values_function".

**Live examples:**

**Case #1:** You have an entity object and want to get a label of the value of the field with options.

```
$field_name = 'field_state';

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition */
$field_definition = $entity->{$field_name}->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition();

// This is a list (array) of options for the field definition:
// [{option1_key} => {option1_value}, {option2_key} => {option2_value}, ...]
$field_allowed_options = options_allowed_values($field_definition, $entity);

// If the field is NOT multiple.
/** @var string|\Drupal\Component\Render\MarkupInterface $field_value_label */
$field_value_label = $field_allowed_options[$entity->{$field_name}->value];

// If the field is multiple.
$field_value = array_column($entity->{$field_name}->getValue(), 'value', 'value');
/** @var string[]|\Drupal\Component\Render\MarkupInterface[] $field_value_labels */
$field_value_labels = array_intersect_key($field_allowed_options, $field_value);
```

**Case #2:** You don't have an entity object but you want to get a list of all allowed options of the field of the entity.

```
$entity_type_id = 'node';
$field_name = 'field_state';

$entity_fields_definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions($entity_type_id);

/** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition */
$field_definition = $entity_fields_definitions[$field_name];
$field_allowed_options = options_allowed_values($field_definition);
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help as well:

```
$node->field_state->getFieldDefinition()->getSetting('allowed_values');
```

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 8 you can use the `view()` method which will render the field, so you can use its markup:

```
$rendered_state_field = $entity->get('field_state')->view(['label' => 'hidden']);
```

then, the path to the label of the selected value should be:

```
$rendered_state_field[0]['#markup']
```

If you want to use it in a twig, then you can simply pass `$rendered_state_field` as a variable.

Answer (score -1):

drupal 7 way:

```
$jid = $row->job_id_181;
if($jid)
{
    $jobNode = node_load($params['jid']);
    $key = $jobNode->field_job_location['und'][0]['value'];//2
    if($key)
    {
        $field = field_info_field('field_job_location');
        $label = $field['settings']['allowed_values'][$key];
        echo $label;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps some one in future.