# Fetch select label via GraphQL

Tags: 9

My nodes have an "articleType" property, which is a select field with ~10 options ("article|Article", "training|Web based training" etc).

Fetching the property via [GraphQL (8.x-3.1)](https://drupal-graphql.gitbook.io/graphql/v/8.x-3.x/) works, but this gives me the key of the selected option (`training`):

```
    [...]
    results {
      entityLabel
      ...on NodeArticle {
        fieldArticleType
      }
    }
    [...]
```

I would like to retrieve the label of the selected option (`Web based training`). How can I do that?

(Related, but without GraphQL: [How to access a selected label instead of value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224484/how-to-access-a-selected-label-instead-of-value))

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new GraphQL field:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\GraphQL\Fields;

use Drupal\graphql\GraphQL\Execution\ResolveContext;
use Drupal\graphql\Plugin\GraphQL\Fields\FieldPluginBase;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * Returns the label for the "article type" field
 *
 * Example: "Themendossier" label instead of "dossier" key.
 *
 * @GraphQLField(
 *   id = "article_type_label",
 *   type = "String",
 *   name = "articleTypeLabel",
 *   nullable = true,
 *   multi = false,
 *   parents = {"NodeArticle"}
 * )
 */
class ArticleTypeLabel extends FieldPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function resolveValues(Node $value, array $args, ResolveContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) {
    $options = $value->field_article_type->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()
        ->getSetting('allowed_values');

    yield $options[$value->field_article_type->value];
  }
}
```